# Problem Occurred When Importing Database! Please Make Sure The Database is Empty

Tags: laravel, web, xampp

I buy script from codecaynon while installing it. I create a empty database in xampp and give name in database credentials but that page come out again and this time if i again write details in database it saying it need a empty database and this cycle going on...........

I want to run code on localhost but instead it showing me this error while I have all requirements it need